# How to create a new case and return the case by clicking a button

Tags: apex

My scenario is, by clicking a button in a visualforce page, I need to create a new Case which preferable opens the standard New Case creation page. And after saving the new case, the related function can return the newly created case. Any suggestions/sample code for that?

I am pretty new to Salesforce development and time doesn't allow me to go through the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redirect to `/500/e?retURL=%2F500%2Fo` which is the "new case" standard salesforce URL which you see when you click on the standard "New Case" button.

Create a command button and a method in your APEX code that will redirect to that URL.

For an example:

`<apex:commandbutton value="New Case" action="{!createNewCase}" />`

then in your apex code

`public PageReference createNewCase()
{
    return new PageReference('/500/e?retURL=%2F500%2Fo');
}`

Alternatively you can do that with HTML or Javascript:

HTML anchor: `<a href="/500/e?retURL=%2F500%2Fo">New Case</a>`

Javascript event on a button : `<input type="button" value="New Case" onclick="window.location.href = '/500/e?retURL=%2F500%2Fo';" />`

> EDIT (upon understanding the question better):

1) Create another VF page and controller but this time using the case standard controller - see [this](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm). This way is easier for you to understand, later on you can merge the two into 1 page, but let's leave it for now I don't want to make it complicated for you :).

2) In the above example, the `retURL` parameter should be your VF page with the standard controller e.g. `(/500/e?retURL=%2FYOURVISUALFORCEPAGENAME`). In the controller of this page you should create a method which will be called by the page's `action` parameter, which will redirect back to your original VF page, but this time including the ID in the parameter. The code in the controller should be something like this:

```
public Case caseRecord {get; set;}

public YOURCONTROLLERNAME(Apexpages.standardController controller)
{
    caseRecord = (Case)controller.getRecord();
}

public PageReference redirectBackToOriginalPage()
{
    return new PageReference('/apex/YOURORIGINALVISUALFROCEPAGE?caseId=' + caseRecord.Id);
}
```

3) In your controller of the original VF page, in the constructor or the action method you should then get the ID of the case after we redirect. So you should have something like:

```
String caseId {get; set;}

public ORINIGALCONTROLLER()
{
    if (String.isNotBlank(Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('caseId')))
    {
        caseId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('caseId');
        // now you can use caseID to query more info and display whatever you like on your page
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this, you need to tailor it to your existing code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was also thinking of this. But how can I get the newly-created case by using this?

Comment: What do you mean by getting the case? Salesforce will automatically redirect to the new case if you use this URL.

Comment: Yes, but I need to get the new case in original page and display the new case ID. It is something like creating a new object by using look-up field. Does it make sense?

Comment: Then in your question you should say "return to the original page and get the case ID" :). I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: Thank you again for the detailed response. I haven't created any VF page for creating a new case. Does it look like this? <apex:page standardController="Case" extension=...>
  <apex:detail />
</apex:page>

Comment: You don't have to, remember, you are redirecting to the standard salesforce new case page, but then upon saving you're redirecting to your custom one which utilises the standard controller. In that page you're getting the newly created record ID and straight after you're redirecting again back to your original page but this time you have the record ID passed in the URL parameter caseID. So your new VF page is just for getting the record ID and forwarding it to your original. You don't need to display anything, you almost can't see this page appearing, it acts like a middle man.

Comment: I guess I understand how it works now. Thank you so much for the detailed response.

Comment: Still one more question: If my original page looks like: .../apex/xxx?id=... how can I add a ?caseId after that?

Comment: If you're question is about adding parameters through apex, then use `Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().put('name', 'value');`

Comment: I guess my question is, for this line: PageReference('/apex/YOURORIGINALVISUALFROCEPAGE?caseId=' + caseRecord.Id); if my original visualforce page already contains a parameter, how can I add something after that? ?id=xxx?caseId=xxx doesn't seem to work

Comment: The questionmark means that there are parameters coming after that point. For each additional parameter you need to add `&` instead. E.g `?Id=123&caseId=1234&otherParam=otherValue`

Comment: Cool. Thank you for that. I have so little previous experience in html. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Got  another issue. It seems I don't know how to call public PageReference redirectBackToOriginalPage() for the new page. It seems to me I can't rewrite standard functions and I can't add any button in that new page

Comment: You can call the redirect method by the `action` tag in your VF page.